# how to compile an Android NDK lib to a static iOS lib

Tags: ios, makefile, android-ndk, static-libraries, porting

I have a C++ codebase which is used by our Android project via JNI (build scripts and such are all Android-specific). I need to update our Objective C project with it which is using an older version of the same library. Problem is that I have only the Objective C code but not the old C++ code and iOS makefiles (they were done by an external agency) - only a binary .a file. How can I generate such a static iOS lib from the JNI code, where to start? I'm reading this right now: http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/ and will update this post with more details if you are interested in helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you having specific problems in trying this? Assuming the code is cross platform and can run on iOS you simply need to either create a new makefile (Android's are specialized) or drag the files in a new or existing XCode project.

Apple's Clang can compile (and you can certainly mix) C, C++ and Obj-C. If you need to for example mix Obj-C and C++ name your file .mm and go.

Example Makefile (note: sloppy but should illustrate!):
http://pastebin.com/ZyrsfT87

Comment: thanks @nuskooler, so the first question would be how to convert `Application.mk` to an LLVM/GCC build... couldn't find tutorials on this. I see several `Makefile.Lib`s hanging around as well, but not sure what to do with them, obviously just getting a `make: *** No targets.  Stop.`

Comment: @ber4444 here is an example Makefile that builds sqlite for iOS 5.0.1. It's pretty sloppy but should illustrate the general concept. Basically you're dealing with standard Makefiles at this point + a few extra Apple only commands for GCC or Clang/LLVM: http://pastebin.com/ZyrsfT87

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck.  iOS and Android don't share the same ABI.  Even if you could do the linker magic to pull symbols out of an ELF shared library and link them to a Mach binary, the functions would crash because things like argument passing and stack frame setup are different (honestly, I don't know the details except that iOS is not EABI).   This is just barely possible if you're willing to write or generate assembly level thunking layers for each function.  But basically: you're SOL.

Comment: thanks @andy-ross, but I'm not thinking about binary compatibility - I have the source files, just not sure how to build them for iOS and how to port the NDK-specific part. Will update my question with more details soon.